# Text editor with Android-like suggestion strip for desktop

Tags: keyboard

After typing on Android and then on desktop PC (no matter the platform) I realize I miss something like the suggestion strip  on the virtual keyboard

[image]

It is enabled by default in Gboard

[image]

I realize this cannot work on desktop in the same way as on touchscreen devices with virtual keyboard, but I'm curious if something similar exists for computers. I imagine a such strip could be displayed on the screen while numbers, arrows or other keys, beside the mouse, could be used to select .

Comment: This feature is built into Windows 10: 

Settings -> Devices -> Typing 

Scroll down to "Hardware Keyboard".
Turn on the "Show suggestions as I type" button. Suggested words can be selected by mouse clicks or by arrow keys. 

This will work all across windows, in all apps, even within your browser (it might actually get annoying). 

For a full explanation, see [this Microsoft support page][1] 


  [1]: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/enable-text-suggestions-for-inclusive-classrooms-8ca3ea32-66b1-4d9d-abf1-1d0ead34f2a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE

Comment: @1NN Just an FYI, markdown in comments is limited _(see Help at bottom right of the comment box)_, so a URL would be specified individually via `[text](link)`

Comment: @JW0914 thanks, actually I should know... Can't edit my comment anymore, unfortunately...

Comment: On askubuntu: [Word Prediction like Android “keyboard”](https://askubuntu.com/q/1125541/925128). In fact this feature is present on iOS too.

Comment: @1NN - you should post that as an answer for Windows.